# PHP, generate PDF file from HTML

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, mpdf

I'm a novice when it comes to generating pdf files

I've tried tcpdf and mpdf but not getting the format the way i want it be.

Here's my mpdf code

```
include('./mpdf.php');
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssForTable.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Client Details</th>
        <th colspan="2" width="50%"><h2 style="padding-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;text-align: center"><strong>ROAD TRAFFIC ACCIDENT</strong></h2></th>
        <th width="25%">Legal HQ</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" colspan="2">
            <strong>Instructed Another Solicito?</strong> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; No &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <th width="50%" colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            Claiming For:<br />
            Personal Injury &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" />
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;No &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" /><br />
            Vehicle Damage &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" />
                             &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;No &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" /><br />
            Loss of Earnings &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" />
                             &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;No &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr><th colspan="2"><h3 style="padding-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;">ACCIDENT DETAILS</h3></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Date of Accident</th>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Time of Accident</th>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
        <th width="25%">No of Occupants (inc driver)</th>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Location of Accident</th>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="50%" colspan="2" rowspan="2" valign="top" >
            <strong>Were Police Involved? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                No &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" />
            <br />
            <br />If so, Police No/Station: </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" colspan="2" rowspan="2" valign="top"><strong>Accident Circumstances</strong><br /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%" colspan="2">
            Is Client:<br />
            Owner <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 15em; margin-bottom: 7px;" /><br />
            Driver &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 15em; margin-bottom: 7px;" /><br />
            Passenger &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 13em;" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Weather Conditions</th>
        <th width="75%" colspan="3">        
            <label style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Sunny &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></label>
            <label style="margin-left: 8em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Rain &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></label>
            <label style="margin-left: 8em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Snow &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></label><br />
            <label style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Ice &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></label>
            <label style="margin-left: 8em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Fog &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /></label>
            <label style="margin-left: 8em; margin-bottom: 7px;" > Dark &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>';


    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
```

The above code generates the following PDF file (screen shot)

[image]

Where as it should look like the following

[image]

My question is, is there a way to generate PDF as we generate HTML I mean is there a way to print whatever html+PHP has generated on client side?

Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, mpdf is quite capable, if annoying at times. I have used 5.7.2 quite recently. I suggest you start using css to position those elements or restructure your table to have checkboxes in separate cells. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: No exactly the answer, but if goal is fill/write PDF with dynamic data from Web form, you can have an original PDF (with common elements/layout), and update it PHP (using fpdf) to generate a custom document.

Answer (score 2):

HTML2PDF converters may be overstrained with that layout. You may should consider PDF-Generators with more powerful layout-options.
The downside is, that you have to define your layout in another layout-language, but this will guarantee a satisfying output.
Have you considered to use [XSL/FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/) with a suitable generator like [PDFnow](http://www.pdfnow.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Here is the complete code.
It works perfectly. 
You can get value from another page using post method also. Your choice.

```
<?php $student_id = $_GET['student_id']; ?>
<?php
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$html .= "
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-image: url(\"images/ok.jpg\");

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:10pt;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
td { vertical-align: top; 
    border-left: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    border-right: 0.6mm solid #000000;
    align: center;
}

p.student_id{
    padding-left : 140px;
    padding-top  : -27px;
} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--mpdf                                                                          

<p class=\"student_id\">$student_id</p>


<sethtmlpageheader name='myheader' value='on' show-this-page='1' />
<sethtmlpagefooter name='myfooter' value='on' />
mpdf-->


</body>
</html>
";

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->Output();
?>
```